# Codenameone how to add multiple JSON subentries in a POST query

Tags: json, post, codenameone

I have a REST webservice which allows me to upload user details in JSON format via a POST request. It looks like I can do this using

```
post.addArgument("Name",entry.get("Name").toString());
post.addArgument("JobRole",entry.get("JobRole").toString());
```

"entry" is an ArrayList < MapString, Object>

As you can see in the below JSON I also have the option of sending multiple entries per user (in this case address details) as in this JSON example:

```
{

    "Name":"Fred Flintstone",

    "JobRole":"Quarry worker",

    "Address":[

    {

       "Address1" :"Boulder House",

       "Address2" :"Rock Way",

       "Address3" :"Rock City"

    }

   ]
}
```

I have tried using

```
post.addArgumentArray("Address",entry.get("Address1").toString,entry.get("Address2"))
```

to combine the entries for the user under Address but I get "400: Bad Request" returned. So how do I add multiple entries like this to my request?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are POST style arguments and they are added as regular HTTP arguments not as JSON (it's like submitting a form in HTML).

What you are looking for is something like:

```
ConnectionRequest cr = new ConnectionRequest(url, true) {
   protected void buildRequestBody(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
       // snipped this but you should get the rest...
       os.write("{\"Name\":\"Fred Flintstone\",\"JobRole\":\"Quarry worker\", ...");
   }
};
```

Alternatively you can use the [new terse REST API](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/terse-rest-api.html):

```
Map<String, Object> jsonData = Rest.post(myUrl).body(bodyValueAsString).getAsJsonMap();
```